# Usage of degenerate dimension in another fact table

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

How can I use degenerate dimension in another fact table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a degenerate dimension is one where the attributes are kept with the measures in the fact table, and not in a dimension table.

E.g, if you fact table is for retail sales, then the receipt number would be kept in the fact table, as otherwise you would be creating a dimension with a cardinality comparable to that of the fact table.

So, I’m having some trouble understanding your question. How can the degenerate dim be kept on a different fact (sic) table? How would you join the two? If you have a key to join, then it’s not a degenerate dimension.

If you mean “can I join two fact tables by a degenerate dimension attribute” the answer is probably not. The join would most likely be many to many, and it would involve joining two huge tables, which would be highly expensive.

Comment: For example: I purchased an Item. The receipt ID is a degenerate dimension from the sales fact table. If I want to return the item, I want to use that ID to connect the item to the devolution fact table. Can I do that?

Comment: I would avoid joining the two tables togetgher, though. I believe it's best to keep both entries in the same table, one with a positive quantity and total price another with signs switched.